# Multiple segues to one UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

In my storyboard I have a `TextInputViewController` (subclass of `UIViewController`). I have multiples push segues leading to TextInputViewController with different identifiers from various view controllers. However every time one of these segues are called they seem to go to the same instance of `TextInputViewController` which causes a very strange behaviour.
Is there a way to make each segue create a different instance of `TextInputViewController`?

Comment: Segues create a new instance of the destinationViewController.  What behavior are you seeing that makes you think they're using the same instance?

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing that out, you are correct, the problem seems to be elsewhere. Write it as answer and I'll mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segues always create a new instance of the destinationViewController (with the exception of the *unwind segue* which simply returns to a previously created viewController).

The behavior you are seeing must be caused by some other state external to the viewController since it is a new instance.

[You can read more about using Segues here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingSegues.html)